# What is the benefit add position:relative to every layout element?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

in many website's source code i saw `position:relative` is added to every `div` which makes layout and no #wrapper div being used?

Is it good practice to add `position:relative` to every layout `div`? Is it related to IE 6 only?

this is css

```
 .header { position: relative; float: left; left: 143px; width: 977px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffff33; } 
.top-nav { position: relative; float: left; left: 143px; width: 977px; height: 30px; } 
.top-nav { margin: 0 0 3em 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; background-color: #f2f2f2; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; } 
.top-nav li { float: left; } 
.top-nav li a { display: block; padding: 8px 15px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: #069; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; } 
.top-nav li a:hover { color: #c00; background-color: #fff; } 
.wrapper { position: relative; float: left; left: 143px; width: 977px; background-color: ffffff; } 
.left { position: relative; float: left; left: 0px; width: 193px; background-color: ea0101; } 
.middle { position: relative; float: left; left: 10px; width: 551px; background-color: fff; } 
.right { position: relative; float: right; right: 0px; width: 213px; background-color: 356aa0; } 
.footer { position: relative; float: left; left: 143px; width: 977px; height: 100px; background-color: #c79810; }
```

Comment: Your four-hundredth question...

Comment: I've never heard of adding `position: relative` to every single `div`.  Where have you seen this?

Comment: The simple answer to your question: no.

Comment: “Your four-hundredth question” — four hundred and first, I think, but Stack Overflow does run on questions, so there really should be some sort of badge for it.

Comment: Is it not good to ask more question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the main reason I can think of, which involves a bug in IE6/7.  It involves elements incorrectly overflowing outside their containers when a parent element requires a scrollbar.  The solution is to add `position:relative` to the parent element. Perhaps the owners of the websites you're looking at just took it to a crazy extreme?

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/

Answer (score 1):

Giving an element `position: relative` triggers [the mysterious `hasLayout` property](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) in IE 6 and 7.

Triggering `hasLayout` often fixes various CSS issues in IE, so *some folks* blindly apply it to every `<div>` in the hope that IE will behave as a result.

*Real* developers only use it when they need to.

Comment: so using blindly can create any other conflict?

Comment: Yup. Once an element is positioned relative, all its descendant elements can only be positioned relative to that element, rather than to the viewport. That usually won’t be a problem, but it could be.